# Localize text of Bootstrap 5 paginator links

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-5, laravel-9

When setting `\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::useBootstrapFive();` at the `\App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class, the `links()` method generates the following text at the bottom left of the page:

> Showing 1 to 10 of 13 results

How can we translate it into other languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Solution

Add these translations:

1. 'Showing'
2. 'to'
3. 'of'
4. 'results'

---

##### Addendum

To customize the pagination views:

[Customizing The Pagination View](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view)

> However, the easiest way to customize the pagination views is by
> exporting them to your `resources/views/vendor` directory using the
> `vendor:publish` command:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`

> This command will place the views in your application's
> `resources/views/vendor/pagination` directory. The
> `tailwind.blade.php` file within this directory corresponds to the
> default pagination view. You may edit this file to modify the
> pagination HTML.

---

```
resources
|
└───views
    |
    └───vendor
        |
        │
        └───pagination
                bootstrap-4.blade.php
                bootstrap-5.blade.php
                default.blade.php
                semantic-ui.blade.php
                simple-bootstrap-4.blade.php
                simple-bootstrap-5.blade.php
                simple-default.blade.php
                simple-tailwind.blade.php
                tailwind.blade.php
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I needed to change the strings of the localization methods from __("Showing") to @lang('pagination.Showing'), though.